# mgf of a poisson distribution -- what am I doing wrong?

Tags: statistics

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here, can someone please explain? Thank you so much in advance!

[image]

Comment: You evaluated the sum incorrectly. Try writing it as $e^{-\lambda}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{(e^t\lambda)^k}{k!}$ and using the power series for $e^x$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything is correct up to the step "Plug in":  $$M(t) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty e^{tk} \frac{e^{-\lambda} \lambda^k}{k!}.$$  Then you drop the summation symbol, and from there, things deteriorate rapidly.  You can't just arbitrarily plug in a value for $k$, when $k$ is an index of summation over the nonnegative integers.  Rather, you should write $$M(t) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty e^{-\lambda} \frac{(e^t \lambda)^k}{k!}.$$  Now, let $\lambda^* = e^t \lambda$, so that you get $$M(t) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty e^{-\lambda} \frac{(\lambda^*)^k}{k!}.$$  If the term $e^{-\lambda}$ were instead $e^{-\lambda^*}$, then this sum would be $1$, because it is a sum of the probability mass function of a Poisson random variable with parameter $\lambda^*$ over its support.  So, how could we **adjust** this expression?  It's simple:
$$\begin{align*} M(t) &= \sum_{k=0}^\infty e^{-\lambda} \frac{(\lambda^*)^k}{k!} \\
&= \sum_{k=0}^\infty e^{-\lambda} e^{\lambda^*} e^{-\lambda^*} \frac{(\lambda^*)^k}{k!} \\
&= e^{-\lambda} e^{\lambda^*} \sum_{k=0}^\infty e^{-\lambda^*}\frac{(\lambda^*)^k}{k!} \\
&= e^{\lambda^*} e^{-\lambda} \\
&= e^{\lambda^* - \lambda} \\
&= e^{e^t \lambda - \lambda} \\
&= e^{(e^t - 1)\lambda}. \end{align*}$$  This works because $\lambda^*$ is not a function of the index of summation $k$, so we are free to multiply and divide by this factor as needed, much like how we might write $$\frac{x}{\sqrt{x-1}} = \frac{x \sqrt{x-1}}{\sqrt{x-1} \sqrt{x-1}} = \frac{x\sqrt{x-1}}{|x-1|}.$$  And as you can see, $e^{-\lambda^*} e^{\lambda^*} = 1$, so we have not changed the value of the sum when we inserted this factor into the sum in the second step.  Then, moving to the third step, we pull out the constant (with respect to $k$) factor $e^{-\lambda}e^{\lambda^*}$ from the sum.

Comment: Hello! Thank you so so much for the detailed answer. I'm confused at the step where you adjust the expression. Do you have to multiple one side by  e^(*λ) and the other by e^(*-λ) ? Or can you just multiply e^(-λ) by e^(*λ) [the series expansion] ?

Comment: @NookLines See my edited response above.

Comment: Oh, got it, thank you soso much for all the help!

Comment: Not _everything_ is correct up to that point.  It said "for $x=1,2,3,\ldots$", but it should start at $0$, not at $1$. $\qquad$

Comment: It's not the sum of a Poisson random variable over its support; it's the sum of the _pdf_ over the support. $\qquad$

Comment: @NookLines : When you multiply by $e^{\lambda^*} e^{-\lambda^*}$, you're multiplying by $1$, since $e^{\lambda^*} e^{-\lambda^*} = 1$.  The point then is that you have $$ \sum_{k=0}^\infty e^{-\lambda^*} \frac{(\lambda^*)^k}{k!} = 1, $$ so there's another multiplication by $1$. $\qquad$

Comment: @MichaelHardy As long as we're being pedantic, it's not a PDF.  It's a PMF.

Comment: @heropup : True. One could argue that it's a density with respect to counting measure and thus a pdf, but of course more specifically it's a pmf.

Answer (score 1):

One "typo" is where you write "for $x=1,2,3,\ldots$", but you need "for $x=0,1,2,3,\ldots$", starting with $0$ rather than with $1$.

Just *why* you plugged in $k=0$ and expected to get the answer from that is a mystery to me.

You correctly wrote:
$$
M(t) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty e^{tk} e^{-\lambda} \frac{\lambda^k}{k!}. \tag 1
$$
Notice that in $(1)$, the factor $e^{-\lambda}$ does not change as $k$ goes from $0$ to $\infty$ and therefore can be pulled out:
$$
M(t) = e^{-\lambda} \sum_{k=0}^\infty e^{tk} \frac{\lambda^k}{k!}.
$$
The last sum can be written as
$$
\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(e^t \lambda)^k}{k!}. \tag 2
$$

Now remember a basic result from calculus:
$$
e^a = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{a^k}{k!}. \tag 3
$$

Just apply $(3)$ with $a= e^t \lambda$, and that tells you the value of the sum in $(2)$, and then consequently that of the sum in $(1)$.